# Exception handling ASP .NET Core MVC 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, error-handling, asp.net-core-mvc

My present configuration:

```
public void ConfigureDevelopment(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    //app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    //app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();

    app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/error/{0}");
    app.UseExceptionHandler();
    Configure(app);
}
```

I have this controller that is supposed to be executed when the server register any exceptions. When I execute "error/test" I'm redirected to "error/500" as expected. If I manually execute "error/exception", I get the server 500 native error, not mine.

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    [Route("error/404")]
    public ActionResult Error404()
    {
        return View("404");
    }

    [Route("error/500")]
    public ActionResult Error500()
    {
        return View("500");
    }

    [Route("error/test")]
    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        return new StatusCodeResult(500);
    }

    [Route("error/exception")]
    public ActionResult Exception()
    {
        throw new Exception("Should redirect to error/500");
        return Content("nope");
    }
}
```

Any idea how to redirect "error/exception" to "error/500" when exception is thrown in actions?

Thank you.

Comment: could be useful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, no problem.  use `app.UseExceptionHandler("/error/500");`  and then this isn't needed any longer:

```
[Route("error/exception")]
public ActionResult Exception()
{
    throw new Exception("Should redirect to error/500");
    return Content("nope");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can specify multiple routes on one action so you dont need the "Exception" action, just add it's route to the 500:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    [Route("error/404")]
    public ActionResult Error404()
    {
        return View("404");
    }

    [Route("error/500")]
    [Route("error/exception")]
    public ActionResult Error500()
    {
        return View("500");
    }

    [Route("error/test")]
    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        return new StatusCodeResult(500);
    }

}
```